# change colour of `echo` for particular line in shell script in Linux?

Tags: shell-script, escape-characters, echo, ansi-term

I want to change the colour of echo for a particular statement in a Linux shell script

example :

```
  echo "invalid entries"
  echo "valid entries"
  echo "valid entry"
```

I want the red color for `echo "invalid entries"` statement; the rest of them should be same as the default color.

Comment: What's the result of `echotc Co`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `tput` to get the control sequences (if they exist) for the user's terminal:

```
red="`tput setaf 1`"
green="`tput setaf 2`"
cyan="`tput setaf 6`"
bold="`tput bold`"
norm="`tput sgr0`"

echo "${red}invalid entries${norm}"
echo "valid entries"
echo "valid entry"
```

Comment: its not working all echo's are having same default color

Comment: Perhaps your terminal doesn't support colour.  What's `$TERM` set to?  And what does `tput setaf 1 | od -a` say?  I checked the above as a `dash` script in an `xterm` and on `linux` (Linux virtual console), both successfully.

Comment: `echo "$TERM"`  says `xterm`

Comment: So the `tput` line should give `esc   [   3   1   m`, if your definitions are correctly installed.

Comment: i just copied your text in a script and execute that script, but its not working, i am a newbie to Linux can you plz help how to write this

Comment: Should work! Strange.. `tput -V` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -e "\e[31minvalid entries\e[0m"
```

Reference: [Bash tips: Colors and formatting (ANSI/VT100 Control sequences)](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)

Comment: Don't embed hard-coded control sequences in strings like this - they look awful on many terminals.

Comment: @TobySpeight Example?

Comment: What do you mean, "example?"?  Are you asking for environments where embedded literal terminal escapes appear badly?  `M-x compile` frequently shows up the idiots who do this (as a single example), if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Plus not all terminals support ANSI color control sequences, or have their own sequences. It is better to go via `termcap` or `curses` - as per Toby's answer (as `tput` will work out the best control sequence for your terminal type).

Comment: @TobySpeight Yup.

Comment: @DravSloan: Yup

Comment: Agree with both of you. It was a quick one

Comment: @Neuron your code also not working on in my file, it is showing default color